# 2d array representation

Tags: java, c, logic, multidimensional-array

The question is not tied to a specific programming language, but rather to minimalistic code and abstraction.

I have this array of 3 rows and 3 columns - imagine a board in which you'd play Tic-Tac-Toe (or naughts and crosses).

When a key(on the Phone) is pressed a value of 0 or 1 is added to the array(1 for X and 0 for O) in the position corresponding to the key pressed(key 9 being board[2][2]).

In building the GUI, I need to map the array coordinates to pixels, such that if: 
[0][0] - 10,10
[0][1] - 10,50
[0][2] - 10,90
...
[2][2] - 90,90

the drawing will take place while traversing the array in a nested loop, but I got stuck on how to write in fewest lines of code as possible the mapping between 0 = 10, 1 = 50 and 2 = 90.

One way to go would be to use a switch for each case. Another would be using an if.

Any other ideas to write this in fewer possible lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( y = 0; y < 3; ++y )
{
    for ( x = 0; x < 3; ++x )
    {
        pos_x = x * 40 + 10;
        pos_y = y * 40 + 10;
        // Draw...
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, exactly what I was thinking :) I think it may need to be either 3 for your upper limit or use <= instead of <

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  int xPos = i * 40 + 10;
  int yPos = j * 40 + 10;
  //set accordingly
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your index value as multiplicator i.e. 90 = 2 * 40 + 10, 50 = 1 * 40 + 10